# Error Querying OrientDB: Cannot query demodb database

Tags: database, crud, orientdb

Hi i'm new to OrientDB and i'm having querying errors with the latest version 3.2.2. GA Community Edition.

When using the default database "DemoDB" and going to the graph tab, using the query SELECT * FROM 'Profiles' I get a long list of errors that says "Error parsing query: SELECT * FROM 'Profiles' ^ Encountered "FROM "" at line 1, column 10. Was expecting one of ... and the error repeats itself with the name of the database at the bottom name ="demodb" Error Code "1"

I've checked the schema and I do see 'profiles' is listed there. I even done this with lower-case and still come across the same error.

How can I successfully query using CRUD with these errors? What is this error message saying?

Comment: Hi, do you have a name with quotes? 'Profiles' not Profiles?

Comment: Hi yes, was following a tutorial and it used 'Profiles'. I removed the quotes and the query works now so far. Could you or someone else explain exactly what the error message means? I would like to know for future reference, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For version 3.2.2 backticks are not needed when referencing classes.

Comment: Already answered. This could be in comments section.-

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using quotes to state the name of the class, are not needed you may use backtick '`' if you need to escape some special characters

```
select * from Profiles
```

or

```
select * from `Profiles`
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes I figured it out. I believe the older 3.0 version uses backticks and the newer 3.1 version is without them.